# Flex items not wrapping in column-direction flexbox

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox

I have an `outerWrapper`, `innerWrapper`, and children. `outerWrapper` has a height of `300px`, and is `display: flex`. `innerWrapper` is also `display: flex`, and is `flex-direction: column`.

When I add `align-items` with a value of anything but `stretch` to `outerWrapper`, the children display one long column. They ignore the `300px` height. Here's an image of how it displays:

[image]

It should display like this:

[image]

Just with `align-items: flex-end`.

Why is this happening, and how can I use `align-items: flex-end` and have the children display like the second image?

#### JSFiddle

```css
#outerWrapper {
  height: 300px;
  background-color: lightgreen;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: flex-end;
}
ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: column;
}
li {
  list-style-type: none;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: lightblue;
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<div id="outerWrapper">
  <ul id="innerWrapper">
    <li class="child">I'm #01</li>
    <li class="child">I'm #02</li>
    <li class="child">I'm #03</li>
    <li class="child">I'm #04</li>
    <li class="child">I'm #05</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**Update**

The answer to this question, is to add a height of `210px` to `innerWrapper`. But I need to get to that number using JavaScript, because the amount of boxes will be dynamic.

I tried the following code:

```
innerWrapper.style.height = (lastChild.offsetTop - innerWrapper.offsetTop + lastChild.offsetHeight) + 'px';
```

but it didn't fix it. It just made the height to: 5 * 102 (5 = number of boxes; 102 = height + border).

How can I set the correct height to `innerWrapper` using JavaScript? (I can't do height: 100% because I won't be able to set align-items: flex-end or center.)

#### JSFiddle

```js
var innerWrapper = document.getElementById('innerWrapper');
var lastChild = innerWrapper.lastElementChild;
newHight = lastChild.offsetTop - innerWrapper.offsetTop + lastChild.offsetHeight;
innerWrapper.style.height = newHight + 'px';
```

```css
#outerWrapper {
  height: 300px;
  background-color: lightgreen;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: flex-end;
}
ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: column;
  /*height: 206px;*/
}
li {
  list-style-type: none;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: lightblue;
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<div id="outerWrapper">
  <ul id="innerWrapper">
    <li class="child">I'm #01</li>
    <li class="child">I'm #02</li>
    <li class="child">I'm #03</li>
    <li class="child">I'm #04</li>
    <li class="child">I'm #05</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've defined a height for `#outerWrapper`: `height: 300px`.

Just give the child – `#innerWrapper` – an equal height: `height: 100%`. Now they wrap.

Then, if you want the items positioned at the container bottom, use flex `auto` margins on the odd-numbered items.

Use an invisible pseudo-element to make the last odd-numbered item always align with the top row.

```css
#outerWrapper {
    height: 300px;
    background-color: lightgreen;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: flex-end;
}

ul {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: 100%;                           /* NEW */
}

li {
    list-style-type: none;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: lightblue;
    border: 1px solid;
}

li:nth-child(odd) { margin-top: auto; }      /* NEW */

ul::after {
    content: "";                              /* NEW */
    width: 100px;                             /* NEW */
    height: 100px;                            /* NEW */
    border: 1px solid;                        /* NEW */
    visibility: hidden;                       /* NEW */
}
```

```html
<div id="outerWrapper">
    <ul id="innerWrapper">
        <li class="child">I'm #01</li>
        <li class="child">I'm #02</li>
        <li class="child">I'm #03</li>
        <li class="child">I'm #04</li>
        <li class="child">I'm #05</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

[**Revised Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/woba6o5p/5/)

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the `height` of the flexbox container:

```
ul {
    ...
    height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That fixes this problem, but then produces a new problem. If you try dong `align-items: flex-end` or `center`, it won't have any effect.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're achieving, but is it what you need - https://jsfiddle.net/woba6o5p/1/ no need to set the div to flexbox.

Comment: Not exactly... I want it like the second image posted in the question, just the `innerWrapper`'s end should be at the end of `outerWrapper`'s end

Comment: What you described in your previous comment doesn't match the image in the question I think. Do you need the blue blocks to align to the bottom of the green container?

Comment: How about it like this? - https://jsfiddle.net/woba6o5p/2/ set width and height on the `ul` tag.

Comment: Yes. That's exactly what I want! Is there a way to do that dynamically? Meaning, how can I set the correct height of the `ul`? JavaScript is fine too. Should I ask that as a new question?

Comment: Thanks. I don't remember what the problem was, and don't have too much time to go into it, and check it out. But thanks for reposting the answer!

Answer (score 0):

Since both the `outerWrapper` and menu element have `flex` positioning, you'll have to make some adjustments to the menu elements' dimensions and alignment as well. Here's an updated fiddle with the behavior you're looking for / matches the second image:

https://jsfiddle.net/wtyqo1su/1/

```
#outerWrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: lightgreen;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

ul {
  height: 250px;
  width: 300px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

li {
  list-style-type: none;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: lightblue;
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

I restricted the `ul` to a specific width / height (so the children would actually wrap as expected). Let me know if you have any questions!

Comment: Thanks! But I aslo want `flex-direction: column;`

Comment: Yeah, sorry just noticed that. I've updated the answer to actually do what you wanted it to do. ;)

Comment: When I try `flex-end`, nothing happens. (I'm going to have to do `flex-start, center, flex-end`)