# Make height dynamic

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox

I have an `outerWrapper`, `innerWrapper`, and children. `outerWrapper` has a height of `300px`, and is `display: flex`. `innerWrapper` is also `display: flex`, and is `flex-direction: column`. `innerWrapper` doesn't have a height set to it.

When I add `align-items:` with a value of anything but `strecth` to `outerWrapper`, the children display one long column. They ignore the `300px` height. Here's an image describing it:

[image]

When it should be like this:

[image]

If I set a height, I will get the second image. i.e. the way I want it to look. I can't set a fixed height, it needs to be dynamic.

I tried the following:

```
innerWrapper.style.height = (lastChild.offsetTop - innerWrapper.offsetTop + lastChild.offsetHeight) + 'px';
```

but it didn't fix it. It just made the height to: 5 * 102 (5 = number of boxes; 102 = height + border).

How can I set a dynamic height to `innerWrapper`? (I can't do `height: 100%` because I won't be able to set `align-items: flex-end` or `center`.)

#### JSFiddle

```js
var innerWrapper = document.getElementById('innerWrapper');
var lastChild = innerWrapper.lastElementChild;
newHight = lastChild.offsetTop - innerWrapper.offsetTop + lastChild.offsetHeight;
innerWrapper.style.height = newHight + 'px';
```

```css
#outerWrapper {
  height: 300px;
  background-color: lightgreen;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: flex-end;
}
ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: column;
  /*height: 206px;*/
}
li {
  list-style-type: none;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: lightblue;
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<div id="outerWrapper">
  <ul id="innerWrapper">
    <li class="child">I'm #01</li>
    <li class="child">I'm #02</li>
    <li class="child">I'm #03</li>
    <li class="child">I'm #04</li>
    <li class="child">I'm #05</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**Update**

I don't think this is a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37928322/when-apply-align-items-column-doesnt-work-properly). It's more of a follow-up question.

Comment: *I can't do `height: 100%` because I won't be able to set `align-items: flex-end` or `center`.* Actually, I think you can achieve the layout you want with `height: 100%`: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37934783/3597276

Comment: Have you tried adding `flex-grow: 1` to your `<ul>`? Also, you should look up `flex-basis`. Flexbox is notorious for ignoring specified dimensions in many situations. This is by design.